How to specify a parameter as a function from a specific class in JSDoc?
I'm working on a JavaScript class and using JSDoc for documentation. In the constructor, I have a parameter mutationAlgorithm that should accept a function from the Mutation class (e.g., Mutation.insert()). Here’s my current constructor:
/**
 * @param {???} mutationAlgorithm - A function from the Mutation class.
 */
constructor(mutationAlgorithm = Mutation.insert) {
    this.mutationAlgorithm = mutationAlgorithm;
}

// Usage:
const obj = new Class(Mutation.insert);

I want to specify in the JSDoc that:

This parameter is a function
This function must be from Mutation class

What is the correct JSDoc syntax for this?

What is the use case for this? Why shouldn't they be able to provide any callback function that obeys the protocol?

Perhaps you could define a MutationAlgorithm class that you wrap around the functions.

Although that just pushes the problem back a level, since then you need to ensure that you only wrap Mutation.xxx functions in MutationAlgorithm

@Barmar Of course they can provide any callback function. I just want to inform the user that this function accepts Mutation class functions as parameter. You know, to help the developer to understand what kind of parameters to pass this function.

I see, it's more like advice than restriction. That might be more appropriate for a free-form comment, since you're not expecting a type checker to use it.

// Algorithms are available in the Mutation class

You can't use @param {Mutation.insert} or @param {typeof Mutation.insert} to enforce that the parameter is specifically Mutation.insert. One way would be to use the callback tag for your usecase.
Example
/**
 * A mutation algorithm function.
 * @callback Mutation~insert
 * @param {string} foo - example param although u have none in your provided code
 * @returns {void}
 */
class Mutation {
    /**
     * Your insert function
     * @type {Mutation~insert}
     */
    static insert(foo) {
        // ...
    }
}

/**
 * @param {Mutation~insert} mutationAlgorithm - Your insert function from Mutation class
 */
constructor(mutationAlgorithm = Mutation.insert) {
    this.mutationAlgorithm = mutationAlgorithm;
}

Explanation
From the JSDoc documentation: The @callback tag provides information about a callback function that can be passed to other functions, including the callback's parameters and return value
Think of @callback as a way to define what a function looks like. What goes in (parameters) and what comes out (return type). After the callback is defined, you can use its name wherever you need to specify that a param should be of that type of function. This way you can change the function and only have to adjust the JSDoc at one place.

As I understand it, it's not specifically Mutation.insert. it can be any static method of the Mutation class. Mutation.insert is just the default value.

Yes, you're correct. Any static method of the Mutation class can be used as the parameter, with Mutation.insert serving as the default value.

Yes @Barmar is right. I want to inform the user that it should be a function from Mutation class. It could be any of them not just insert.

/**
 * @description Get type for Mutation Class itself
 * @typedef {typeof Mutation} MutationClass
 */

/**
 * @description Utility type to filter out only functions from passed type
 * @template T
 * @typedef {T extends (...args: any[]) => any ? T : never} PickFunctionOnly
 */


/**
 * @description keyof get all keys for static properties of class. Than we filter out only functions
 * @typedef {PickFunctionOnly<MutationClass[keyof MutationClass]>} MutationStaticFunctions
 */

class Class {
  /**
   * @param {MutationStaticFunctions} mutationAlgorithm 
   */
  constructor(mutationAlgorithm = Mutation.insert) {
    ...
  }
}

